# Async function returning empty value then doing operations?

Tags: node.js, async-await

Hey I have written this code in node js

```
async function getUdemydata(){

    try{
        var finalData = []
        const res = await axios.get(baseUrl)
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);

        $('div[class="content"]').each(async (i,el) =>{
            const courseTitle = $(el).find("a").text()
            const aa = $(el).html() 
            const courseUrl = await getCoupenCode($(el).find("a").attr("href"))
            const courseDescription = $(el).find(".description").text().trim()
            const courseImage = await formateImageUrl($(el).find(".image").html())
            var dataObj = {
            "title": courseTitle,
            "description": courseDescription,
            "image": courseImage,
            "link": courseUrl
            }
            finalData.push(dataObj);
            console.log('appended');
        })
        return (finalData);
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }

}

(async()=>{
    var rs = await getUdemydata();
    console.log(rs);
})()
```

When I call the `getUdemydata()` function only the empty array is printed after that **appended** which is inside the function is being printed what should I change in the code so that the function will return the final array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `.each` is as follows:

```
each<T>(fn: (i: number, el: T) => boolean | void): Cheerio<T>
```

It is not `Promise`-aware, so does not `await` the async function you supply as its parameter.

Remember that an async function is just a normal function that returns a `Promise`, so you could map these function calls, ending up with an array of `Promise`, then wait for them all.

```
// var finalArray = [] // <-- NO
const promises = $('div[class="content"]')
    .toArray()
    .map(async (el,i) => {
        // same body as `each` in your code
        // except, don't push into `finalArray`
        // just return your value

        // finalData.push(dataObj); // <-- NO
        return dataObj;
    });
const finalArray = await Promise.all(promises);
```

or if the parallelism of running all those promises at once is too much, then the documentation suggests that a [`Cheerio` is `Iterable`](https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html), so just loop over `$('div[class="content"]')` with a normal

```
for(const el of $('div[class="content"]')) { //...
```

Comment: ...as an aside, bearing in mind that every other higher-order function over arrays tends to call its selector with `index` as the *2nd* parameter, the parameter-order of `.each(index, element)` bucks the trend in a "set-you-up-to-fail" kind of way

Comment: @AnishGowda I made an edit to the code because it is not necessary to push items into `finalArray`